# how to create a shooting bullet using gamemakers built in physics

Tags: game-maker, gml

I'm new to GameMaker, and to making games, for my second game ever I was just going to use GameMakers built in physics. It's a RPG and I'm having lot's of trouble getting the guy to shoot the bullet. I can get the bullet to be placed in the room and at the angle it needs to be at. You could normally then just use the objectnamehere.speed = to what ever you want your speed to be. But! using physics you could use the phy.speed but that's a read only variable. So i half to use the phy_speed_x and phy_speed_y. But how do I get it to shoot in the direction the bullet object is? Here's the code I have so far.

```
// Player shoot
var shootButton = mouse_check_button_pressed(mb_left);
var bulletSpeed = 10;

if (shootButton) {
    bullet = instance_create(ot_player.x, ot_player.y, ot_bullet);
    bullet.phy_rotation = phy_rotation;
    bullet.phy_speed_x = bulletSpeed;
    bullet.phy_speed_y = bulletSpeed;
}
```

I have tried putting many different variables where I have the bulletSpeed variables but nothing has seem to work. I'm stuck here, I've watch tutorials and read lots of stuff but nothing has worked!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

var shootButton = mouse_check_button_pressed(mb_left);
   var bulletSpeed = 10;

```
if (shootButton) {
    bullet = instance_create(ot_player.x, ot_player.y, ot_bullet);
    with(bullet) {
        phy_rotation = other.phy_rotation;
        ldx = lengthdir_x(15, -phy_rotation)
        ldy = lengthdir_y(15, -phy_rotation)
        physics_apply_impulse(x, y, ldx, ldy);
    }
}
```